# Excel convert from yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss to MM

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to convert a column from yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss to Months

an actual example is as follows

[image]

The reason is, I would like to gather how many calls have been done every month possibly in a graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Mid to pull the month number:

```
=--MID(E2,6,2)
```

to get the month name we need to parse the string to an actual date:

```
=TEXT(LEFT(E2,10),"MMMM")
```

Comment: Thanks alot Scott ! 

Can I change the number into Name (Ie Jan, Feb ...etc)

Comment: You stated `MM` which is number return not name.

Comment: =CHOOSE(--MID(K7,6,2),"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec") would do it.

Edit: Darn it Scott, why do you have to be so good at this?

Comment: @IlikeExcelverymuch yes, I thought about that but in the end it was easier and shorter to make it a string that Excel could recognize as a date.

Comment: @ScottCraner , Thanks alot, I tried =TEXT(O2*29,"mmmm") on the numbers resulting from   =--MID(E2,6,2) & also worked

Comment: `=TEXT(LEFT(E2,10),"MMM")` should work and be more concise. @Haitham

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

=TEXT(A1,"M")

Will return a number from 1 to 12. If you want the full month written out use "MMMM".

Comment: Excel will not natively be able to convert `2020-01-01T19:34:00.2548323Z` to a time and as such this formula will not work unless you parse the string.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought that was a formatted number date code.